# Fetch all data from a table grouping by two columns - mysql, php

Tags: php, mysql, fetch, group-concat, categorization

I am trying to fetch every details I have on my table but group them by two different column names one after other and fetch the same from php

example:

```
   id   name    url     category    subcategory
/*------------------------------------------------------/*
    1   google  g.gl    partner     associative
    2   fb      f.b     sponsor     main
    3   yahoo   y.ho    partner     color
    4   stack   st.ck   sponsor     main
    5   mys     l.my    sponsor     sub
    6   bang    b.lo    sponsor     parent
    7   xyz     x.yz    partner     color
```

what I finally want

```
       id   name    url     category    subcategory
    /*------------------------------------------------------/*
        1   google  g.gl    partner     associative
        3   yahoo   y.ho    partner     color
        7   xyz     x.yz    partner     color
        2   fb      f.b     sponsor     main
        4   stack   st.ck   sponsor     main
        6   bang    b.lo    sponsor     parent
        5   mys     l.my    sponsor     sub
```

firstly category is grouped and ordered by id, and subcategory is then grouped and ordered by subcategory in ascending order.

also, how could i fetch the same using php

my try:

mysql:

```
SELECT category, GROUP_CONCAT(subcategory) , GROUP_CONCAT(name) , GROUP_CONCAT(url) 
FROM list
GROUP BY category
```

PHP:

```
1. mysql_fetch_array to fetch everything..
2. explode subcategory and every other concated values and then echo them
```

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: to an organizations website, in which partners are sorted first and related sub partners are listed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also try this Code:

```
<?php 
$db_resource    = mysqli_connect('Host Name', 'username', 'password');
$dbconn         = mysqli_select_db('Data base Name', $db_resource);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM list order by category , subcategory';
$result = mysqli_query($query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    print_r($row);

}
?>
```

Comment: By the way, you're mixing `mysqli_` with `mysql_` @user3016038